# How to store Bitmaps in GridView adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap

I have a gridview menu which has 6 grid items, each of which contain a Bitmap background Image, the gridView adapter for this gridView is shown below...

public final class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Bitmap bitTemp;

public GridAdapter(Context context) {

    //Create a bit object
    Bit bit = new Bit(R.drawable.rec2);

    //Store bitmap inside a bitmap object
    bitTemp = bit.blurredBitmap1;



    //Inflater
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    //Add data items here
    mItems.add(new Item("Mon",bitTemp,R.drawable.pic1));
    mItems.add(new Item("Tues",bitTemp,R.drawable.pic2));
    mItems.add(new Item("Wednesday",bitTemp,R.drawable.pic3));
    mItems.add(new Item("Thursday",bitTemp,R.drawable.pic4));
    mItems.add(new Item("Friday",bitTemp,R.drawable.pic5l));
    mItems.add(new Item("saturday", bitTemp,R.drawable.pic6));


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i).drawableId2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View v = view;
    ImageView picture,mainBtn;
    TextView name;


    if (v == null) {

        //Inflate gridItem layout
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);

        //Set Tag
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        v.setTag(R.id.mainBtn,v.findViewById(R.id.mainBtn));


    }


    //Cast items
    picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
    name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);
    mainBtn = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.mainBtn);



    Item item = getItem(i);


    //Link to item class
    name.setText(item.name);
    picture.setImageBitmap(item.bitmap1);
    mainBtn.setImageResource(item.drawableId2);


    return v;
}


//Create Bitmap images class

public class Bit extends Object{


   public Bitmap blurredBitmap1;

   Context context;



    Bit(int resId) {

       Bitmap bitmapTemp;

      //Convert image into Bitmap
      bitmapTemp =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),resId);

      //Then blur image
      blurredBitmap1 = BlurBuilder.blur(context,bitmapTemp);





    }




}
```

}

Below is the class that contains the data items that will be passed into the List items....

```
// Grid data class 

       class Item {

        public final String name;
        public final Bitmap bitmap1;
        public final int drawableId2;




           Item(String name, Bitmap bitmap1,int drawableId2) {

               this.name = name;
               this.bitmap1 = bitmap1;
               this.drawableId2 = drawableId2;





           }




    }
```

The class "bit" constructs blurred bitmap images which takes in a resource id parameter, this is initialized in the GridAdapter Constructor

```
   public GridAdapter(Context context) {

        //Create a bit object
        Bit bit = new Bit(R.drawable.rec2);

        //Store bitmap inside a bitmap object
        bitTemp = bit.blurredBitmap1;
......

}
```

However when i run this code i get an error...

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxTVH.png)

Please provide a simple answer as i am quite new to android,

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context in class Bit is null,because you do not init.
so the code

```
bitmapTemp =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),resId);
```

throw NullPointException.